# How do I get Dell Firmware Updates on Elementary OS

Tags: hardware, drivers

I can't find docs, other than Dell pages saying it's automatic on Ubuntu. There is a .exe installer available from their downloads page, but there are no instructions for setting up on other distros. I'm using Dell XPS 9360.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer after a lot of searching is to install the firmware management tool:

```
sudo apt-get install fwupd
fwupdmgr get-devices
fwupdmgr get-updates
fwupdmgr update
```

These upgrades (if available), may require restart. I am upgrading currently from BIOS 1.2.3 to 1.3.2, and it requires a restart.

I found this information on this [community page](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/b/techcenter/archive/2016/02/02/dell-firmware-updating-under-linux)

The [github page for fwupd also has more info](https://github.com/hughsie/fwupd/)

For people with other recent machines, this might well provide an upgrade mechanism for their BIOS / firmware too.

Comment: Update, firmware installer screen came up on boot, and completed successfully.